# How to check the order of a numbers in a list with other list?

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have a list with the below values in ascending order.

> l1 = [1,3,9]

There are 6 possible permutations and length of each permutation is length of l1.

```
(1, 3, 9)
(1, 9, 3)
(3, 1, 9)
(3, 9, 1)
(9, 1, 3)
(9, 3, 1)
```

I need to delete all the permutations which follow the order from l1.

[1,3,9]  1,3 matches the order in l1.

[9,1,3]  1,3 matches the order in l1.

[3,9,1]  3,9 matches the order in l1.

The answer should be 6-3 = 3
 Mycode:

```
from itertools import permutations
l = [1,3,9]
perm = permutations(l, len(l))
res = []
for i in list(perm):
    res.append(i)
    for i in res:
    for j in range(0,len(i)):
        if i[j] and i[j+1] in l[j]:
        res.remove(i)
    print(len(res))
```

I get type error. How do I fix this and also **if** statement

Comment: Try: `if i[j] in l[j] and i[j+1] in l[j]`

Comment: `l[j] ` is an integer, maybe you'd want to do `i[j] in l and i[j+1] in l`, even though I'm not sure it will solve the problem , it solves the `TypeError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create neighbor-tuples from your original data and check if any tuple from your permutation is inside the list of your original - only if not: add to result:

```
from itertools import permutations
l = [1,3,9]

# create all neighbor-tuples 
tups = set(zip(l,l[1:]))
perm = list(permutations(l, len(l)))
print("perm: ", perm)
res = []
print("tups: ", list(tups))
for i in perm:
    itups = zip(i,i[1:]) # create neighbor tuples from this permutation
    if any( t in tups for t in itups):
        continue
    res.append(i)

print(len(res)) 
print(res)
```

Output:

```
perm:  [(1, 3, 9), (1, 9, 3), (3, 1, 9), (3, 9, 1), (9, 1, 3), (9, 3, 1)]
tups:  [(3, 9), (1, 3)]
3
[(1, 9, 3), (3, 1, 9), (9, 3, 1)]
```

Documentation:

- [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)